# keycloak gateway ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after login

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

Using a basic setup with just keycloak + keycloak gateway + a basic hello world server in a docker-compose.yaml, i bind the ports to localhost.

in the browser on hittint localhost:3000/app, it asks for login, after login it goes into a loop of 307's until it gives the error

```
skynet redirected you too many times.
```

this is the docker logs

```sh
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503597710125e+09  error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503597711482e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001417, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/app"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503597758873e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001075, "status": 307, "bytes": 303, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/authorize"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503598393035e+09  info    issuing access token for user   {"email": "", "expires": "2019-05-13T12:30:59Z", "duration": "4m59.1607132s"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503598394403e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0488485, "status": 307, "bytes": 37, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/callback"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.557750359842182e+09   error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503598422916e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001062, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503598452325e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001103, "status": 307, "bytes": 303, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/authorize"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599140193e+09  info    issuing access token for user   {"email": "", "expires": "2019-05-13T12:30:59Z", "duration": "4m59.0860053s"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599142253e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0468151, "status": 307, "bytes": 37, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/callback"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599177747e+09  error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599179156e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001666, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599206538e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0000965, "status": 307, "bytes": 303, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/authorize"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.557750359972925e+09   info    issuing access token for user   {"email": "", "expires": "2019-05-13T12:30:59Z", "duration": "4m59.0270923s"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599730272e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0356627, "status": 307, "bytes": 37, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/callback"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599757788e+09  error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599758906e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0001187, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503599789677e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0000897, "status": 307, "bytes": 303, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/authorize"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503600374641e+09  info    issuing access token for user   {"email": "", "expires": "2019-05-13T12:31:00Z", "duration": "4m59.9625537s"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.557750360037571e+09   info    client request  {"latency": 0.0470309, "status": 307, "bytes": 37, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/callback"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.557750360040543e+09   error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503600406244e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0000851, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503600438595e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0000815, "status": 307, "bytes": 303, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/authorize"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503600930834e+09  info    issuing access token for user   {"email": "", "expires": "2019-05-13T12:31:00Z", "duration": "4m59.9069331s"}
gatekeeper_1  | 1.5577503600936885e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.0345039, "status": 307, "bytes": 37, "client_ip": "172.31.0.1:47246", "method": "GET", "path": "/oauth/callback"}
```

this is my /etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.132   skynet
```

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  appserver:
    image: python:2-alpine
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 80
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./appserver.py:/appserver.py
    command: [python, /appserver.py]

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.0
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U keycloak -d keycloak"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:        keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER:      keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  password
    volumes:
      - pg-storage:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 8s
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR:                POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR:                  postgres
      DB_DATABASE:              keycloak
      DB_USER:                  keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA:                public
      DB_PASSWORD:              password
      KEYCLOAK_USER:            admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD:        secret
      # PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  gatekeeper:
    image: keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./gatekeeper.yaml:/gatekeeper.yaml:ro
    command: [
      --config, "/gatekeeper.yaml",
      --enable-logging, "true",
      --enable-json-logging, "true",
      --verbose, "true"
    ]

volumes:
  pg-storage: null
```

this is my gatekeeper config

```
listen: 0.0.0.0:3000
discovery-url: http://skynet:8080/auth/realms/justice-league
upstream-url: http://skynet:8081
# redirection-url: http://192.168.1.132:3000


client-id: service-gatekeeper
client-secret: a02a7867-b713-4b1f-81d7-6bfd07ec7937
enable-default-deny: true
encryption_key: AgXa7xRcoClDEU0ZDSH4X0XhL5Qy2Z2j

match-claims:
  aud: service-gatekeeper
  iss: http://skynet:8080/auth/realms/justice-league


resources:
- uri: /app
  methods:
  - GET
  roles:
  - service-gatekeeper:edit
  require-any-role: true
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but... We had this problem and it was caused by network latency, by the time Keycloak was receiving the initial token to dispatch the access token, the initial token was already expired and the cycle was startet again.

We increased the Client login timeout and it solved the problem.